# Why does type need to be defined twice?

Tags: java, generics

Currently this is the way we define type: in case below Type - Integer. It looks redundant to declare type twice.

`FindMiddleStack<Integer> fm = new FindMiddleStack<Integer>();`

I guess java could have been smart enough to allow 
`FindMiddleStack<Integer> fm = new FindMiddleStack();`
or
`FindMiddleStack fm = new FindMiddleStack<Integer>();`

Why did they not do the simple route ( ie to define type only once, either at left or at right, or the declaration) ?

Comment: This is how it was defined when generics was introduced, you would have to ask the designers why

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it invokes guess work into the intentions of the origins designers of the API

Answer (score 5):

Because it would be a special case and complicate the language.

`FindMiddleStack<Integer> fm = ...` declares a variable of type `FindMiddleStack<Integer>` called `fm` with the initial value of whatever the `...` evaluates to. It doesn't care what the `...` is.

`new FindMiddleStack<Integer>()` creates a `FindMiddleStack<Integer>`. It doesn't care how that `FindMiddleStack<Integer>` is used.

In Java 7, they did put in the extra effort to make it possible, and you can do this:

```
FindMiddleStack<Integer> fm = new FindMiddleStack<>();
```

Comment: *Because it would be a special case and complicate the language* it is not. The compiler only raise warnings and does its job by notifying the problems of using these approaches, but both cases compile.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ... what? `<>` was not valid until Java 7 after it was shown that the benefits outweigh the costs; generics were introduced in Java 5.

Comment: Both approaches can compile using Java 5, but they have different meaning. IMO that was the motivation to create diamond operator. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Java is *smart enough* since Java 7 by usage of [diamond operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html):

```
FindMiddleStack<Integer> fm = new FindMiddleStack<>();
```

---

Note that using this approach:

```
FindMiddleStack<Integer> fm = new FindMiddleStack();
```

You're initializing your generic class with a raw type, which raises a warning but you can work with `Integer` elements in fm and the compiler will check it.

The other way:

```
FindMiddleStack fm = new FindMiddleStack<Integer>();
```

You have a raw class initialized with a generic, which also raises a warning. But this case is worse than the first one, since the compiler cannot check the generic elements that will be used in `fm`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question... Isn't because you can have different types in the declaration and creation?

Comment: @Anubian not in the form `Collection<Animal> a = new ArrayList<Cat>()` (that would have bad consequences, they made that mistake with arrays and we're still paying for it). You can however have  `Collection<? Super Animal> a = new ArrayList<Cat>()` although I can't see that being very useful (it's more useful as a method argument or return)

Answer (score 0):

Because semantically you are creating two different things, whose type just happens to match.

On the left hand side you are creating a reference, and on the right hand side you are creating an operator, and the assignment operator connects one to the other.

Also, the type of the reference can be different from the type of the object. E.g.

```
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

If you adopted your solution of writing the type only once, how would you deal with this problem?

However, the semantic sugar in Java 7 to avoid writing the type twice when it is intended to be the same is welcome, even if it can be confusing. For example, if the following works:

```
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then does list point towards an

```
ArrayList<Integer>
```

or an

```
ArrayList<Number>
```

?

I don't know if the code snippet above works in Java seven, but if it does I am uncomfortable with the idea that changing the reference type in one part of the code can change the type of object instantiated elsewhere, it could create very brittle code.

Comment: `List<Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();` doesn't compile even in Java 5.

Comment: `List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); list = new ArrayList<>();` compiles in Java 7 and 8. The problem there is that no matter how you initialize it, you cannot add elements into that list since you don't know which type should be there.